# How to use git pull to pull data using php exec

Tags: php, git, ssh

The code I tried to pull is

```
shell_exec('git init');
$d = shell_exec('git fetch origin master');
$output = shell_exec('git pull origin master');
```

But it is not working as expected. Sometimes it is working and sometimes it doesn't.

I have two-factor authentication enabled in my git account. Do you think is the reason?

or need to do anything else to pull data?

Comment: You initialize empty git repo and try to fetch and pull from "nothing". Have you cloned repo, do you have refs to origin?

Comment: Also try some lib that already solved lots of issues. E.g. https://github.com/czproject/git-php

Comment: @Justinas: No, that's what i did only

Comment: @Justinas: i tried this lib but i don't know how to use it for existing repo

Comment: @Justinas: Using lib, I am getting Command 'git fetch origin "master"' failed (exit-code 128).

Comment: For existing repo you should `git clone {giturl}` otherwise it will not work. Try these commands in CLI and will see if it works

Comment: @Justinas i tried this but not working $repo = GitRepository::init('gitrepo');
  $repo->pull('origin master');

Comment: Please read again: **YOU DON'T HAVE REMOTE REPOSITORY SET**. Your git does not know from where to pull master

Comment: @Justinas: if i use $repo = GitRepository::cloneRepository it is giving me error that Repo already exists after runing once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212841/discussion-between-justinas-and-bhumi-shah).

Comment: The problem that also needs to be solved is the user that script will be ran under (PHP CLI, FPM or FastCGI). You need to ensure that it has access to the credentials to copy the repository (if it is private) and write access to the directory you are attempting to clone repository into.

Answer (score 1):

the code you wrote, creates a new repository in the current working directory and then tries to fetch/pull from the `origin` remote but none has been configured yet.

you need to add something similar to `shell_exec("git remote add origin GIT_URL");` where `GIT_URL` is your repository remote url

---

also you’re not doing any error checking, maybe try it with `exec` `system`, or `proc_*` to be able to see detect a failures and abort when needed

Comment: And additionally you need to either provide a certificate or your login, if your repo needs authentication.

Comment: Maybe he is authenticated, but OP didn't specify it in question.

Comment: that’s where handling error is useful, he’ll see what is causing problems. it’s hard to enumrate all possible solutions all possible features he wants :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, using [`czproject/git-php`](https://github.com/czproject/git-php), and its [`pull` function](http://czproject/git-php):

```
$repo = GitRepository::init('gitrepo');
$repo->pull('https://url/remote/repo', array('master'));
```

That way, you specify the remote URL explicitely.

Comment: I tried this as well. not working!! it i use clone, it is giving error

Comment: it was not giving any error just, it is not pulling data

Comment: @BhumiShah Strange, it does work for me. See also https://packagist.org/packages/czproject/git-php#user-content-cloning-of-repository

Answer (score 0):

Use `system()` instead of shell_exec

You can also do a

```
$escaped_cmd = escapeshellcmd($command);
system($escaped_cmd);
```

if you're paranoid

Answer (score 0):

You should have **`origin`**(The remote repository) before starting fetch.You missed the **`git remote add origin URL`** command after initialization on repository in local machne. Also, if you've created fresh empty repository in local maching, you'll be needing to **clone** the existing remote repository first. Here is how you can clone the repository from the remote server.

```php
$repo = 'YOUR_REPOSITORY_URL_HERE';
shell_exec('git clone '.$repo);
shell_exec('git remote add origin '.$repo);
$d = shell_exec('git fetch origin master');
$output = shell_exec('git pull origin master');
```

make sure the repository is not private, else you'll need **ssh** to connect the remote server.

I suggest you not to go through re-inventing the weel, You can use [git-php](https://github.com/czproject/git-php) library to make code hasslefree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to behave like I'm trolling, but:
1st: Learn the workflow of git - you'll need to clone your repository, then checkout master, then git pull. If you've done that once - You must not use "git clone" anymore, only checkout master and do git pull.
2nd: You need to set your ssh key to PHP - I would not do that, but that's your thing. Using 2 factor authentication has to do nothing with the problem you are trying to solve.
Simply use the SSH URL from Github to clone your repository and make sure, that PHP can access your SSH Key so it can authenticate to github.